# Unknown error in JavaScript multiple choice quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiple-choice

I tried to make it as basic as absolutely possible with the constraints I was given. scores had to be in arrays, and there had to be two numeric inputs for age and BMI.

In the HTML code, it's all radio elements aside from the age and BMI questions. There are no errors there, the errors only appear when I try to run with this script in place.

```
function getScore(){

var totscore = 0;
var subscore = 0;

var scores1 = [0, 2, 4];
var scores2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var scores3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var scores4 = [0, 1, 2];

var scoresAge = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var scoresBMI = [0, 2, 4];

var scores6 = [0, 1, 2];

var scores7 = [2, 1, 0];
var scores8 = [2, 1, 0];
var scores9 = [3, 2, 1, 0];
var scores10 = [3, 2, 1, 0];
var scores11 = [2, 1, 0];
var scores12 = [1, 0];
var scores13 = [2, 1, 0];


var subScores = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var scores14 = [0, 1, 2];


//QUESTION 1
if(document.getElementById("q1a").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores1[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q1b").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores1[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q1c").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores1[2];
} else alert ("Question one has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 2
if(document.getElementById("q2a").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores2[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q2b").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores2[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q2c").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores2[2];
} else if(document.getElementById("q2d").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores2[3];
} else if(document.getElementById("q2e").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores2[4];
} else alert("Question two has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 3
if(document.getElementById("q3a").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores3[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q3b").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores3[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q3c").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores3[2];
} else if(document.getElementById("q3d").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores3[3];
} else if(document.getElementById("q3e").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores3[4];
} else alert("Question three has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 4
if(document.getElementById("q4a").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores4[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q4b").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores4[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q4c").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores4[2];
} else alert("Question four has not been finished.");

//AGE QUESTION
var yr = document.getElementById("_age");

if (document.getElementById("_age").isNaN){
    alert("Please input a valid age.");
} else if (yr <= 0){
    alert("Please input a valid age.");
} else if(yr < 55){
    totscore = totscore + scoresAge[5];
} else if(55 <= yr < 65){
    totscore = totscore + scoresAge[4];
} else if(65 <= yr < 70){
    totscore = totscore + scoresAge[3];
} else if(70 <= yr < 75){
    totscore = totscore + scoresAge[2];
} else if(75 <= yr < 80){
    totscore =  totscore + scoresAge[1];
} else if(80 <= yr){
    totscore = totscore + scoresAge[0];
} else alert("Please input a valid age.");

//BMI QUESTION
var ht = document.getElementById("_height");
var wt = document.getElementById("_weight");

if (document.getElementById("_height").isNaN){
    alert("Please input a valid height in inches.");
}
if (document.getElementById("_weight").isNaN){
    alert("Please input a valid weight in pounds.");
}

var bmi = (wt*703)/(ht*ht);

if(bmi <=0){
    alert("Please make sure your height and weight inputs are correct.");
} else if(bmi <= 30){
    totscore = totscore + scoresBMI[2];
} else if(30 < bmi <= 37){
    totscore = totscore + scoresBMI[1];
} else if(37 < bmi){
    totscore = totscore + scoresBMI[0];
} else if(200 <= bmi){
    alert("Please make sure your height and weight inputs are correct.");
}

//QUESTION 6
if(document.getElementById("q6a").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores6[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q6b").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores6[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q6c").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores6[2];
} else alert("Question six has not been finished.");

//SUBQUIZ BEGINS

//QUESTION 7
if(document.getElementById("q7a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores7[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q7b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores7[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q7c").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores7[2];
} else alert("Question seven has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 8
if(document.getElementById("q8a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores8[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q8b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores8[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q8c").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores8[2];
} else if(document.getElementById("q8d").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores8[3];
} else alert("Question eight has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 9
if(document.getElementById("q9a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores9[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q9b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores9[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q9c").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores9[2];
} else if(document.getElementById("q9d").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores9[3];
} else alert("Question nine has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 10
if(document.getElementById("q10a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores10[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q10b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores10[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q10c").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores10[2];
} else alert("Question ten has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 11
if(document.getElementById("q11a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores11[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q11b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores11[1];
} else alert("Question eleven has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 12
if(document.getElementById("q12a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores12[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q12b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores12[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q12c").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores12[2];
} else alert("Question twelve has not been finished.");

//QUESTION 13
if(document.getElementById("q13a").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores13[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q13b").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores13[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q13c").checked){
    subscore = subscore + scores13[2];
} else alert("Question thirteen has not been finished.");

//SUBQUIZ CALCULATION
if(subscore < 0){
    alert("Please make sure you have answered questions seven through thirteen.");
} else if(subscore = 0){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[6];
} else if(1 <= subscore <= 3){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[5];
} else if(4 <= subscore <= 6){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[4];
} else if(7 <= subscore <= 8){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[3];
} else if(9 <= subscore <= 11){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[2];
} else if(12 <= subscore <= 14){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[1];
} else if(subscore = 15){
    totscore = totscore + subScores[0];
} else if(subscore> 15)
    alert("An error has occured. Please restart and try again.");

//SUBQUIZ ENDS

//QUESTION 14
if(document.getElementById("q14a").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores14[0];
} else if(document.getElementById("q14b").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores14[1];
} else if(document.getElementById("q14c").checked){
    totscore = totscore + scores14[2];
} else alert("Question fourteen has not been finished.");

alert(totscore)
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? (Press F12 to view). Copy-paste code is hard to maintain. You probably want to make a function with parameters you can pass for each question.

Answer (score -1):

To cut down on your coding, use JavaScript Assignment Operators.

x += y ( is the same as saying: x = x + y )

So rather than:

```
totscore = totscore + scores1[0];
```

It can just be:

```
totscore += scores1[0];
```

For your age question, ensure it's getting the value of that object:

```
//AGE QUESTION
var yr = document.getElementById("_age");
```

should be:

```
var yr = document.getElementById("_age").value;
```

Same deal with the other element fields you are fetching.